# TYPO3 Hide & Replace Pagetitle in Breadcrumb

Tags: typo3

I have a little problem with my navigation and couldn't get it work...I got on every page a breadcrumb navigation which shows the page tree until the current page.

So far so good but when I go to the details page of my news I got the following tree `Home > Newest > Article`. I don't want to have the page title `Article` here because every other news would have this tree. Instead of the pagetitle I want to have the news title so I modified my navigation like this:

```
30 = HMENU
    30 {
        special = rootline
        special.range = 0 | -1

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            stdWrap.dataWrap = <p>{ date : d.m.Y }&nbsp;:::&nbsp;|

            NO = 1
            NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = | &nbsp; &gt; &nbsp;

                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            }

            CUR = 1
            CUR.allWrap = | </p>

            stdWrap.append = RECORDS
            stdWrap.append {
                if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
                tables = tx_news_domain_model_news

                source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
                source.intval = 1

                conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
                conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
                    field = title
                    htmlSpecialChars = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now the problem: when I click go on a page which is hidden in menus the breadcrumb looks like this `Home >`. Obviously the last page isn't displayed and this should be solved but I don't know how to do it.

At least I tried something with this in some combinations but cant't get it work

```
if {
    value = 46
    equals.field = uid
    excludeUidList = 46 //includeNotInMenu = 1
}
```

When adding `includeNotInMenu = 1` under the special.range hidden pages are shown in the breadcrumb title but then the breadcrum in news looks like this `Home > Newest > Article NewsTitle` and I don't want to have this 'Article' in it. Hope someone of you can help me!

Comment: I'd suggest you to end the breadcrumb _before_ the last page (so 0|-2) and add the last part of the breadcrumb as page title/news title without it being part of the menu, as it is not necessary to link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first:
not displaying the current page is ok only for the news-detail page. so use a condition to realize it:

```
[page|uid = 123]
    30.30.special.range = 1|-2
[global]
```

second:
add the current news title after the menu. the handling is a littel bit easier.

```
    30.40 = RECORDS
    30.40 {
        tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
        source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
        source.intval = 1

        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
        conf.tx_news_domain_model_news {
            field = title
            htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
    }
```

therefore you might need to change the wrap. either split it or (better) give it an additional COA level.

and so the news title only is neccessary on your detail page you put that code into the condition.

**Alternatives:**
you can use `.stdWrap.if` to modify the range of the breadcrumb and the display of the news title, but with the TS-condition you have a smaller typoscript for normal pages (faster rendering).
You even need no condition for the `tx_news_pi1|news` parameter, as the detail page normaly would not show anything (except an error)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For example (since Ext news 7.2) to hide News Detail page in the breadcrumb..

Home > News > News Detail > Article name

```
page.10.dataProcessing {
  100 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
  100 {
    special = rootline
    special.range = 0|-1
    includeNotInMenu = 1
    as = breadcrumb
  }

  110 = GeorgRinger\News\DataProcessing\AddNewsToMenuProcessor
  110.menus = breadcrumb
}

[page["uid"] == {$pages.newsDetail}]
  page.10.dataProcessing.100.special.range = 0|-2
[END]
```

Results in

Home > News > Article name